# Having difficulty linking comments to posts (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, slug

I was getting the error `dispatch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'`. I have tried 
`def dispatch(self, request, slug=none, *args, **kwargs):` and `def dispatch(self, request, slug=title, *args, **kwargs):`. I want people to be able to add comments to posts. I tried a variety of experiments (including the few I listed above) and every experiment lead to an error message I could not resolve.

**ListView is now not working properly**

In trying to fix my problem I managed to prevent ListView from working.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

I added these lines of code to the model which has caused the problem.

```
url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def dispatch(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post)
        comments = post.comments.filter(active=True, slug=slug)
        new_comment = None

        if request.method == 'POST':
            abc
            else:
                xyz
```

**models.py**

*Update - I have tried to add a SlugField based on Pedros comment.*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)



def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView
)
from. import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('facebook/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='blog/index.html'), name="facebook")
]
```

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: Also `DetailView` already handles retrieving your object and 404'ing etc... so you don't need to repeat that stuff yourself in `dispatch`... and you don't want to be doing checks for `POST` requests... if you're expecting stuff to be updated, you're after a different generic view

Comment: Your ``Post`` model is missing a slug field

Comment: John I have now added in my urls.py.

Comment: John which generic view would you recommend? At the moment I am using DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView and DeleteView. I need to make sure any changes are compatible with CreateView, UpdateView and DeleteView.

Comment: Pedro I have now attempted to add a slug field. I have modified my original question.

Comment: John I have now removed the stuff you mentioned from dispatch.

Comment: Why are you overriding `dispatch` in `PostDetailView`? That's unusual and is the direct source of your error message. What did you intend to achieve with that?